# App submission to AppStore issue (entitlements)

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to publish my application on the AppStore, using a Distribution certificate/provisioning profile, but I get the following error when uploading the archive with Application Loader: "Unable to extract entitlements from application".

The doc says an entitlements file is not needed for AppStore submission, so what is the problem?

Comment: Are you using Xcode 4.0+ ? It's infinitely easier to use the in-built submission tool than the app loader - just build the project as archive, and follow the instructions in the window to validate the build and upload it to iTunes Connect.

Comment: No, I'm using Xcode 3.2 for this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove Entitlements.plist file from the project, while creating the AppStore binary.